# Please explain the order of operations of Function.compose()

Tags: java, lambda

default method in `Java.util.function.Function`

```
default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
 Objects.requireNonNull(after);
 return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
}
default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
 Objects.requireNonNull(before);
 return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v));
}
```

`main`

```
Function<Integer, Integer> doubleFunction = x -> x * 2;
Function<Integer, Integer> squareFunction = x -> x * x;

int result1 = doubleFunction.apply(5); //  10
int result2 = squareFunction.apply(5); //  25

Function<Integer, Integer> integerIntegerFunction = doubleFunction.andThen(squareFunction);

int result3 = doubleFunction.andThen(squareFunction).apply(5); // 100
int result4 = doubleFunction.compose(squareFunction).apply(5); // 50
```

Question: statement- `doubleFunction.compose(squareFunction).apply(5)`, `doubleFunction.compose` returns `(V v) -> apply(before.apply(v))`, how does the outer code `apply(...)` run?

`before.apply(v)` returns int number, assume returns symbol res. For `(V v) -> apply(res)`, how this can be regard as doubleFunction's instantiation call.【pool English, sry】

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Function.compose` takes another `Function` as an argument and in essence, "assigns" it to `before` in the default method.

So.

```
int result4 = doubleFunction.compose(squareFunction).apply(5);
System.out.println(result4);
```

is the same as

```
Function<Integer, Integer> before = squareFunction;
int result4 = doubleFunction.apply(before.apply(5));
System.out.println(result4);
```

So first it squares `5` to get `25` and then doubles that to get `50`.